# Is the final keyword necessary in the Java singleton class?

Tags: java, singleton

```
public class MySingleton{
  private static final MySingleton INSTANCE = new MySingleton();
  private MySingleton(){}
  public static getInstance(){
    return INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

Is this the right way to implement a Singleton. If yes then what is the necessity of the final keyword ?

Comment: It's not necessary, but good practice to show that the value is constant.

Answer (score 2):

Final will ensure the instance is not changeable after creation.  If you're only including a constructor, and no setters, it's not a big deal.  No one can change your INSTANCE and you are not changing it.

Not a bad idea to leave it there in case the class is later changed.  Immutability offers some advantages (easier serialization, insurance against someone changing your object behind your back, etc).

It is harder to put immutability back in than it is to take it out.  Write your code defensively so no one can mess it up later.

Answer (score 2):

The generally preferred approach is to use an enum

```
public enum MySingleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

In your example the final keyword shows the intention and will prevent reassignment (= bug) but is not strictly necessary.

In particular, the variable being static, it does not need to be final to be safely published in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: singletons are bad at all, enum singletons cannot be reset by unit tests. so its a true evil singleton, the worst which can happen.

Comment: @AlexWien you can always have your enum implement an interface and stub/mock it.

Comment: @assylias This works in most cases, but not when a third class is involved, which uses that singleton. for the unit tests that have a more integrative scope

Comment: +1.  You shouldn't have to reset your singleton; mutable singletons are just thinly disguised static state, which is evil.

Comment: @assylias  - some thoughts here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/179386

Answer (score 2):

There is no one right way to implement the singleton pattern in Java, however using a public static final instance variable is a good approach provided that you don't need lazy loading and can live with the consequences for unit testing.

If unit testing is an issue and you still want a singleton, consider using dependency injection. This will allow you to configure an ordinary instance with a singleton lifecycle.

The final modifier allows the Java compiler and runtime to make good optimization and thread-safety decisions. I would always use final with this style of singleton declaration. I would go so far as to say it is a bad design choice to allow a singleton instance to be mutable - because client code can no longer rely on seeing the same value for the lifetime of the process.

It is possible to deal with the unit testing issue with a configurable factory class:

```
private static final MySingleton INSTANCE = MySingletonFactory.create();
```

... without losing the benefits of final.

Answer (score 0):

not really necessary. but using final it cannot be reset by the singleton class itself, which enforces a true singleton.
However since singletons are bad practise, they can be made useable for unit tests by adding an setInstance() method. The anxiuous people could define setInstance private, such that the unit test calls the setInstance, via reflection.

Comment: aren't final members initialized only once ? how can it be reset ?

Comment: @user1189932 you missed a word: i wrote not reset

Comment: @AlexWien, can you please explain to me why singletons are bad practice?

Comment: @gumkins because you cannot get rid of that classes once instantiated, they hinder testability, as explained in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

There is another aspect to this which no one seems to be discussing: **making the singleton instance final does not make it immutable**. If the class has additional instance variables, these will be part of the singleton and can be modified by the usual means.